# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-object error on eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have [3 tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77088/8) in my database: `customers, sales, contacts`

- I have a column which is called `planned_contact_date` in the `sales` table. It calculates the contact date a few days after the purchase date. The customer can have more than one records in the `sales` and in the `contacts` table.
- I get the most recent record of the customer from the `sales` table and insert these most recent records into the `contacts` table.
- If I contact the customer, the `contact_date` column of the `contacts` table will be inserted with a new record and row. Else, it is `null`.

In my blade file, I have a table in which I would like to fetch the most recent sale date of the customer and its planned contact date, customer's name and contact date.

`customer` model:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerContact::class);
}

public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

`sale` model:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerContact::class);
}
```

`contacts` model:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}

public function sale()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Sale', 'last_sale_id', 'id');
}
```

In my controller, I successfully fetch the data in this way:

```
CustomerContact::with(['customer', 'sale'])
->where('planned_contact_date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
->get();
```

However, when I delete the `where` condition, it throws this error:

> Trying to get property 'sale_date' of non-object

Isn't the following query enough to merge the related tables?

```
CustomerContact::with(['customer', 'sale'])->get();
```

Blade file:

```html
@foreach($records as $record)
<ul>
   <li>{{$record->customer->id}}</li>
   <li>{{$record->customer->name}}</li>
   <li>{{$record->sale->sale_date}}</li>
   <li>{{$record->planned_contact_date}}</li>
   <li>{{$record->contact_date}}</li>
</ul
@endforeach
```

I need to compare the `planned_contact_date` and the `contact_date`. If the `planned_contact_date` is different than the `contact_date` or `contact_date` is null, then do another action. How to achieve that?

Here is my `customers` table:

[image: customers]

`sales` table:
[image: sales]

`contacts` table:
[image: contacts]

Comment: this is strange: `public function sale() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Sale', 'id', 'id'); }`. The foreign key is id or last_sale_id?

Comment: Upps... I forgot to correct it. The foreign key is last_sale_id of course @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: So you forgot to correct it in your code or is it a typo in this post? btw, it's quite difficult to read in those images of the tables, it would be better if you post the migrations code

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in this post. I have just corrected it. Thanks. Actually, I did not use migration. Tables were created manually before. I have sent an sqlfiddle link in which there is a similar structure of the related tables. Does it help? @porloscerrosΨ

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77088/8

Comment: Well, I can't find anything weird in your code now. Just for debug what I would do is a dump of the result of the query to see what is there, something like `dd($records);`

Comment: It just gives 2555 results with the name of the 'CustomerContact'. However, I am unable to check the array details. So, it can't get the array details with joined tables. I think arrays are empty in the result. @porloscerrosΨ